# Get image attachments with apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, attachment, array

I would like to display the the first image attachment for a record in my visualforce page.

The visualforce page uses a standard controller to get the record data and I've built an extension to retrieve the attachments.

**APEX Extension:**

```
public with sharing class NewsController {

    private final News__c newsArticle;
    public list<News__c> con {get;set;}

    public NewsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.newsArticle = (News__c)controller.getRecord();

    }

    public List<News__c> getPostAttachments() {
        String newsId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        con = new List<News__c>();
        con = [SELECT Id, (Select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate From Attachments Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) FROM News__c WHERE Id = :newsId];
        return con;
    }
...
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page title="{!News__c.Title__c}" standardController="News__c" extensions="NewsController">
...
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, PostAttachments.Attachments[0].Id)}" rendered="{!PostAttachments.Attachments.Size>0}"></apex:image>
```

When saving the VF page I get an error stating

> (NewsPage) Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Attachments'

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

And secondly could someone help me filter this list out so only images are returned (jpg/gif/png) incase a user adds other attachments?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because PostAttachments is already a List, being rendered as a VisualforceArrayList. You're attempting to call PostAttachments.Attachments and then index that here:

```
PostAttachments.Attachments[0].Id)}" rendered="{!PostAttachments.Attachments.Size>0}">
```

It's being thrown because there is no property on PostAttachments called "Attachments." Without being familiar with the structure of your class News__c, I would guess that you should try to index PostAttachments itself and go from there.

Comment: Could you give me an example that I could use or maybe I can add more detail to the question for a better explanation? I'm finding it difficult to understand how I can flatten so there isnt a list within a list.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000113345&language=en_US

Comment: Just try replacing PostAttachments.Attachments[0].Id with PostAttachments[0].id in your URLFOR function and let us know how that goes

Comment: Using `PostAttachments[0].Attachments[0].Id` has worked :D

Comment: For efficiency could you tell me more about trying to flatten the list?